# Using ReactiveSecurityContextHolder inside a Kotlin Flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working on a Spring Boot (2.2) project using Kotlin, with CouchDB as (reactive) database, and in consequence, async DAO (either suspend functions, or functions returning a Flow). I'm trying to setup WebFlux in order to have async controllers too (again, I want to return Flows, not Flux). But I'm having troubles retrieving my security context from `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`.

From what I've read, unlike `SecurityContextHolder` which is using `ThreadLocal` to store it, `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` relies on the fact that Spring, while making a subscription to my reactive chain, also stored that context inside this chain, thus allowing me to call `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` from within the chain.

The problem is that I have to transform my `Mono<SecurityContext>` into a Flow at some point, which makes me loose my `SecurityContext`. So my question is: is there a way to have a Spring Boot controller returning a Flow while retrieving the security context from `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` inside my logic? Basically, after simplification, it should look like this:

```
@GetMapping
fun getArticles(): Flow<String> {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().flux().asFlow() // returns nothing
}
```

Note that if I return the Flux directly (skipping the `.asFlow()`), or add a `.single()` or `.toList()` in the end (hence using a `suspend fun`), then it works fine and my security context is returned, but again that's not what I want. I guess the solution would be to transfer the context from the Flux (initial reactive chain from `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`) to the Flow, but it doesn't seem to be done by default.

Edit: here is a sample project showcasing the problem: https://github.com/Simon3/webflux-kotlin-sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you really try to achieve is accessing your ReactorContext from inside a Flow.

One way to do this is to relax the need for returning a Flow and return a Flux instead. This allows you to recover the ReactorContext and pass it to the Flow you are going to use to generate your data.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@GetMapping("/flow")
fun flow(): Flux<Map<String, String>> = Mono.subscriberContext().flatMapMany { reactorCtx ->
    flow {
        val ctx = coroutineContext[ReactorContext.Key]?.context?.get<Mono<SecurityContext>>(SecurityContext::class.java)?.asFlow()?.single()
        emit(mapOf("user" to ((ctx?.authentication?.principal as? User)?.username ?: "<NONE>")))
    }.flowOn(reactorCtx.asCoroutineContext()).asFlux()
}
```

In the case when you need to access the ReactorContext from a suspend method, you can simply get it back from the coroutineContext with no further artifice:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@GetMapping("/suspend")
suspend fun suspend(): Map<String,String> {
    val ctx = coroutineContext[ReactorContext.Key]?.context?.get<Mono<SecurityContext>>(SecurityContext::class.java)?.asFlow()?.single()
    return mapOf("user" to ((ctx?.authentication?.principal as? User)?.username ?: "<NONE>"))
}
```